# Do moon-landing deniers exist?

Tags: moon

I think it's a reasonably well-established fact that from 1969 until 1972 a total of twelve human beings have walked on the moon. Taking into account the fact that the technology to fake the moon landing didn't exist until after the moon landing and the fact that if NASA was willing to fake accomplishments they would have done so again it's honestly stupid to say that the moon landings didn't happen (unless you're a philosopher claiming that nothing is real or something, in which case I would rather not get into that argument).

All that said, though, everyone has heard the stereotype of either conspiracy nuts or idiots who don't think the moon landings actually happened, though I have never actually met anyone in real life who believes that the moon landings were faked. Are there actually people who claim that the moon landings were faked, or is that just a running joke in modern culture or something of the sort?

Comment: [Buzz Aldrin punched a guy that claimed he's a liar and a thief for saying he walked on the moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OROlF8zB9z0). I think it's pretty obvious those people exist.

Comment: Aside from the question of whether the moon landings were faked... Technology did exist pre-1969 to fake them.  2001 A Space Odyssey was released in 1968.

Comment: In case anyone's disputing notability, [Al Gore](https://thecaucus.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/04/24/gore-gingrich-and-greenhouse-gases/) has said "There are people who still believe that the moon landing was staged on a movie lot in Arizona."

Comment: "_I have never actually met anyone in real life who believes that the moon landings were faked I have never actually met anyone in real life who believes that the moon landings were faked_" - I have never seen a black swan. Does this mean they are fake?

Comment: So now there is such a thing as people denying that moon landing denialism exists? 

Comment: "_I have never actually met anyone in real life who believes that the moon landings were faked_" I'm more impressed by the implied fact that you can read people's minds.

Comment: Relevant meta about this question's notability: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c

Comment: As a frequent contributor to the space exploration Stack Exchange, I assure you that moon landing deniers exist and have too much time on their hands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apart from [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OROlF8zB9z0) which Mad Scientist referenced, there is [a corresponding news article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/2272321.stm):

> **Ex-astronaut escapes assault charge (BBC News Saturday, 21 September, 2002)**
>
> Californian authorities have decided against prosecuting former astronaut Buzz Aldrin after he punched a documentary maker who claimed his moon missions were faked.

Comment: ...at the age of 72. The Right Stuff alright. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they exist.

The previous answer and a previous comment refer to "a guy" who was punched by Buzz Aldrin.  YouTube has the 47-minute documentary made by that guy, Bart Sibrel.

[A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to the Moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xciCJfbTvE4)

Comment: How does this answer add to the existing answer that has been on the site for almost a year?

Comment: It does add an additional YouTube link, and the name of the punchee (and apparent moon-landing denier).  The fact that he made a 47-minute youtube video on the subject probably provides a degree of support for the idea that he actually believed this, as opposed to just trolling an astronaut (I haven't seen the video myself).  Admittedly, it could be written better.